# Refering file path by variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to refer file path through variable in script but not aware of syntax.

```
#!/bin/bash
filepath = /tibcouat1_fs/tibco/deployment/egypt/bnk/broker/logs/;
echo "============BNKBroker=============="
grep 'EXSTAT|' $filepath/bnkbroker.log
```

Find above script I have created where I am getting below error.

```
bash-3.2$ ./BNKSrvcList.sh 
./BNKSrvcList.sh: line 2: filepath: command not found
============BNKBroker=====  =========
grep: can't open /bnkbroker.log
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not have spaces at both sides of the equal sign (=), try this:

```
filepath=/tibcouat1_fs/tibco/deployment/egypt/bnk/broker/logs/
```

Comment: The end of line `;` is OK, but not necessary.

Comment: And we normally don't use the last '/' for a file path, like this: `filepath=/tibcouat1_fs/tibco/deployment/egypt/bnk/broker/logs`, so that later on you can use '/' between you folder path name `$filepath` and the log file name `bnkbroker.log`: `$filepath/bnkbroker.log`

Comment: In bash shell syntax, the assignment of a variable can not go across the space: `A=5 echo $A` means to assign variable A to 5 and then print variable A.  So `Name=John Smith` will assign string John to variable Name, but then Smith will be executed (normally it's an unknown command).  Correct usage is to quote it with single- or double- quotes: `Name="John Smith"`  Similarly, `A=  5` means to assign empty string to `A`, and then execute a command named `5`, which is normally an unknown command.

Comment: this answer made my day

Answer (score 3):

Try using this

```
filepath='/tibcouat1_fs/tibco/deployment/egypt/bnk/broker/logs/';
```

Comment: This is wrong, spaces around `=` are not allowed in BASH variable assignment.